# Rails4 Sprockets; Asset logical path has no extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I recently upgraded to Rails 4, and whilst running my request specs I started getting the following error:

> Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
>        Sprockets::ArgumentError:
>          Asset logical path has no extension: europe
>
> Blockquote# /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:36:in `initialize'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:380:in`new'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:380:in `build_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in`block in build_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in`build_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in`find_asset'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/server.rb:47:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in`block in call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`*run*_515869138317914613_*call*_callbacks'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`block in tagged'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`tagged'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in`each'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in`call'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
>        # /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`block in start_thread'

Is there any way to get Sprockets to accept files without an extension?

Gems:
Sprockets: 2.10.1
Rails: 4.0.2

Comment: Look at [this issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/347)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in your **config/application.rb** file add

```
initializer 'setup_asset_pipeline', :group => :all  do |app|
  # We don't want the default of everything that isn't js or css, because it pulls too many things in
  app.config.assets.precompile.shift

  # Explicitly register the extensions we are interested in compiling
  app.config.assets.precompile.push(Proc.new do |path|
    File.extname(path).in? [
      '.html', '.erb', '.haml',                 # Templates
      '.png',  '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg',         # Images
      '.eot',  '.otf', '.svc', '.woff', '.ttf', # Fonts
    ]
  end)
end
```

so it looks like

```
module ProjectName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    initializer 'setup_asset_pipeline', :group => :all  do |app|
      # We don't want the default of everything that isn't js or css, because it pulls too many things in
      app.config.assets.precompile.shift

      # Explicitly register the extensions we are interested in compiling
      app.config.assets.precompile.push(Proc.new do |path|
        File.extname(path).in? [
          '.html', '.erb', '.haml',                 # Templates
          '.png',  '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg',         # Images
          '.eot',  '.otf', '.svc', '.woff', '.ttf', # Fonts
        ]
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @rodrigoalves its my pleasure to have been able to help

Answer (score 6):

In order to precompile assets you need to move any files without extensions out of app/assets and into vendor/assets.  This is a known issue with sprockets and bower has a warning about it on their readme see https://github.com/stve/bower/pull/4/files

Or you could make sure all files in app/assets has an extension, but that's more time intensive.